# Where to find reference to functions, which come with Chipmunk?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I'm new to iPhone development. I installed cocos2d with chipmunk and try to make a simple project from some tutorial.

When I encounter chipmunk functions (like `cpSpaceAddShape`, `cpSegmentShapeNew`, etc.) where can I find them documented?

Chipmunk API documentation seems to contain only class reference... so can't I find the functions documented in Chipmunk API reference? Where then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said "class reference" you were probably looking at the [Objective-Chipmunk API Reference](http://chipmunk-physics.net/release/Objective-ChipmunkLatest-Docs/annotated.html) which is for the commercial Objective-C port of Chipmunk.

The Chipmunk functions are all documented in the Chipmunk API Reference created by doxygen. I haven't been able to find it online however (same goes for Box2D API Reference) so I started hosting these [API References](http://www.kobold2d.com/display/KKDOC/API+References) myself.

For example, here's the documentation for [cpSpaceAddShape](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/Chipmunk/html/group__cp_space.html#ga5fd6bdb0b93c93a93eeab0611e070080) and [cpSegmentShapeNew](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/Chipmunk/html/cp_shape_8h.html#aec8205ea24a70893adebd2f17ec88bb2) (at the bottom).

Answer (score 3):

Official Chipmunk documention:
http://chipmunk-physics.net/release/ChipmunkLatest-Docs/